# what's wrong with this sql trigger statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing my first sql trigger query.So i am trying to grasp the idea of trigger statement.My plan is to--

> 1.insert data to a table called 'trigger_table';
>
> 2.After insertion ,fetch data from that exact same table and store it to a php variable using PDO;

So i wrote the following trigger statement.And i get this error while executing sql in mysql workbench

> ERROR 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

```
SQL Statement:

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_table_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON trigger_table FOR EACH ROW

-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one

  BEGIN

        SELECT * FROM trigger_table;

    END
```

It would be a great help if anyone guide me towards the right path to accomplish my task.Thanks !

**php code:**

```
   $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=trigger",'root','');
   $sql="INSERT INTO trigger_table (name,email) VALUES('zami','alzami@gmail.com')";
   $conn=$db->prepare($sql);
   if($conn->execute()){
      $result=$conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   }
```

Comment: mysql is NOT the same thing as sql-server. You should only tag the DBMS you are working with. The error is pretty clear though. You can't return results from a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are meant to react to an event to update, modify or delete content.  As the error states, they aren't meant to return data.

Per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html):

> A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. Some uses for triggers are to perform checks of values to be inserted into a table or to perform calculations on values involved in an update.

You may be after a [Stored Routine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html)

> Stored routines (procedures and functions) are supported in MySQL 5.7. A stored routine is a set of SQL statements that can be stored in the server. Once this has been done, clients don't need to keep reissuing the individual statements but can refer to the stored routine instead.

Comment: can stored routine can fetch data on insert without additonal request query?

Comment: Yes.  You can write several statements inside the stored routine, and add in and out parameters.